# Telerik RadTreeViews Ajax Timeout - How to test for timeout

Tags: ajax, telerik, treeview, timeout

I have an Ajaxed RadTreeiew. When its nodes are clicked the information area is populated from the database. However, if ajax has timed out, clicking the nodes will just show nothing in the information area.

I've tried increasing the AsyncPostBackTimeout in the script manager but with no luck. Also tried telerik support.

What i need is to be able to test for the ajax timeout on each node click and if timed out then redirect back to the same page, to refresh it.
Treenode click event below...

```
Public Sub RTV1_ItemClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RadTreeNodeEventArgs) Handles RTV1.NodeClick

    'session timeoutcheck
    If Session(courseID & "-MyTreeView") = Nothing Then
        Session(courseID & "-SiteconID") = 0
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString)
    End If

    'This is a tree node click so set the TabID session to 0
    Session(courseID & "-TabID") = 0

    'expand child nodes here
    e.Node.ExpandParentNodes()
    e.Node.Expanded = True
    e.Node.Selected = True

    'setup the content
    SetUpContent(e.Node.Value, courseID)

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us your code. Maybe there is something wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks Saeid. I've shown the tree node click event.